# C++: Will the iterator of an element in std::map change?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I know that the iterator of an element in vector may be changed, since the vector will double its size when there is no enough space.

So my question is that will the address of an inserted element in map change after other operations?

For example,

```
map<int, int> mp;
mp[0] = 1;
auto i = mp.find(0);
mp[1] = 2;
mp[2] = 3;
cout << it->second << endl;
```

will `it->second` always be `1` if I didn't change the value of `mp[0]` ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think associative containers' (`map`, `set`, etc.) iterators don't invalidate on adding elements. Edit: Yes, they don't.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: So is it compiler-dependent or I can safely assume it won't be changed? Or just not suggested to do so?

Comment: @user1097809 Look at the linked dupe. It's all standard mandated.